# Android BLE max advertisers

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

While advertising i'm getting error 2 : too many advertisers.Any one know how much adverts i can send simultaneously on the same device ? Is it a fixed value or it depends on the device ?

Comment: It depends on the device.